# Running scripted commands within a makefile (Linux make)

Tags: linux, bash, make, makefile

I have battled with this for the most of last night.

I want to rename all the files `xxxx-yyyy` to `xxxx:yyyy` in a folder from a makefile.

I have a `renamefiles.sh` which does the job fine:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $i
 do
   echo $i
   echo mv "${i}" "${f//-/:}";
   mv "${i}" "${f//-/:}";
 done
```

But I'd really like to put this inside a makefile.

The makefile is from OpenWRT/Lede; the snippet where it needs to be is:

```
define Build/Prepare
 $(Build/Prepare/Default)
 tar xvfj $(DL_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_FILENAME) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
 rm -f \
    $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/05c6:1000:sVe=GT
 cp ./data/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/

 ./renamefiles.sh $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/
endef
```

So I would really like to, in the makefile, rename   `$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/????-????` to `????:????`

but whatever I tried, I seemed to get some error (usually `unexpected end of file` from `bash`?).

I'm also looking for a solution which will work without additional prerequisites; e.g. my first research indicated that `rename` would do the job nicely, but I was warned off because it's not available everywhere.

Comment: 1) is `for i in $i` a real copy/paste ? shouldn't it be `for i in $*` ? 2) makefile call should be `./renamefiles.sh $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/????-????`

Comment: Also consider using the `rename` command (packaged on many distros) with perl-style regexp instead of a homemade script.

Comment: @dirkt - see below.  'rename' was my first choice :).

Comment: @Archemar - yes, it was late, and i'd deleted most of my test work already!  thanks for highlighting...;

Answer (score 1):

rather than edit my own question; I thought i would answer it so the question is there to refer to.

Yes, the script didn't work either....

the 'working' script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for i in $1*-*
do
    echo file is $i
    FILENAME=$(basename $i)
    echo filename is $FILENAME
    NEWNAME=${FILENAME//-/:}
    echo newname is $NEWNAME
    rm "$1$NEWNAME"
    mv "$1$FILENAME" "$1$NEWNAME"
done
```

so; corrections:

1. $1 after the for.
2. substitution in the filename is different in #!/bin/sh and #!/bin/bash -
   basically ${FILENAME//-/:} does not work in MY #!/bin/sh....  (note about ${var//xyz/abc} - the two slashes mean 'replace EVERY xyz with abc, a single would mean repalce the first xyz with abc.  Also note that hyphen MAY need to be escaped as it can indicate a range indicator).
3. add 'shopt -s nullglob' before the for loop, else if there are NO matching files, it will give you the search pattern as a file....
4. do subst on filename only, as path had lots of hyphenated directories!

use of 'rename' - was not allowed by the project maintainer :(.

Now on to putting it in the makefile.

1. My original issue was i could not get past 'bash - unexpected end of file'.
   Simple really - everything MUST be effectively on one line.  end lines with (space);(space)\ to cause bash to use the ';' as an end of line marker, and make to use the '\' to indicate you want everything presented to bash on the same line.
2. Use of $.  I read in loads of places that in makefiles, if you were using $ to pass through to bash, then you had to use two (i.e. $$FILENAME).  But I had to use FOUR ($$$$FILENAME).  All i can assume at this point is that in the complex buildroot system of Lede/Openwrt, the makefiles are includes of includes of includes in some way, and i only found 4 by experimentation.  I did't see this in any of the other answered questions about loops in makefiles :).

so, the final makefile snippet:
(note the shopt so that it works even if no files are found)

```
shopt -s nullglob ; \
for filevar in $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/*-* ; \
do \
    echo file is $$$$filevar ; \
    FILENAME=$$$$(basename $$$$filevar) ; \
    echo filename is $$$$FILENAME ; \
    NEWNAME=$$$${FILENAME//-/:} ; \
    echo newname is $$$$NEWNAME ; \
    echo 'rm "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/$$$$NEWNAME"' ; \
    echo 'mv "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/$$$$FILENAME" "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/$$$$NEWNAME"' ; \
    rm "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/$$$$NEWNAME" ; \
    mv "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/$$$$FILENAME" "$(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/$$$$NEWNAME" ; \
done
ls $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_DATA_PATH)/usb_modeswitch.d/
```

I hope this info helps someone else.